# What does Zadroga act cover that would not be already be covered by existing workers comp or other benefits?

Tags: united-states, law

Recently there has been a push to renew the Zadroga act (which I believe was successful). What I don't understand is why the current workers comp / benefits provided to first responders would be insufficient or exclude any of the first responders.

[Jon Stewart went to Washington](http://www.firefightingnews.com/jon-stewart-911-responders-ask-congress-to-extend-health-benefits/) with many firefighters pushing for the act. However, the [New York's guide to benefits](http://www.wcb.ny.gov/content/main/firefighters/FirefightersGuideToBenefits.pdf) states that "An injured or ill volunteer member will have his health care for that condition paid"

What would be covered by this act that would not already be covered by existing workers comp or other insurance?

I could see how unofficial volunteers, victims and other people might not be covered. However, given that the group from the article included injured firefighters imply that they would be receiving at least some of the benefits. How does this bill affect firefighters compared to the normal benefits for being injury in the line of duty?